# F# Subsets of a set

Tags: f#

Hi I'm trying to write a function that takes a list of integers and returns a list of all subsets of that list.

So for example [5;9;7] would return in no particular order [[5;9;7];[5;9];[5;7];[9;7];[5];[9];[7]]

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. I looked on the internet and the only solution I can find is

```
module Set = 
  /// Returns all subset of a specified set. For example, for input [1;2;3],
  /// the result will be a set containing sets [1;2;3], [1;2], [1;3], [2;3]
  /// [1], [2], [3] and [].
  let rec subsets s = 
    set [ // Add current set to the set of subsets
          yield s
          // Remove each element and generate subset of 
          // that smaller set
          for e in s do
            yield! subsets (Set.remove e s) ]

// Sample usage
Set.subsets (set [1 .. 3])
```

However I want to use simple lists instead of the module set. How can I do this with a simple function possibly using List comprehensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is remove each element from the original list (one at a time) and yield the resulting lists, then recursively perform the same operation on the resulting lists as well:

```
let rec getSubLists l =
    [ yield l
      for x in l do
        let rest = l |> List.except [x]
        yield rest
        yield! getSubLists rest
    ] |> List.distinct
```

This should get you all distinct sub-lists of the original list, including the empty list.

```
getSubLists [1;2;3]

val it : int list list = [[1; 2; 3]; [2; 3]; [3]; []; [2]; [1; 3]; [1]; [1; 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function finds all sublists of a list:

```
let rec powerset (xs: 'T list) : 'T list list =
    match xs with
    | [] -> [[]]
    | h::t -> List.fold (fun ys s -> (h::s)::s::ys) [] (powerset t)
```

For a set you can convert the set into a list, call this function, and then convert back to a list of sets:

```
let powerSet (s: Set<'T>) : Set<'T> list = 
    s
    |> Set.toList
    |> powerset
    |> List.map Set.ofList

> [0..2] |> Set.ofList |> powerSet;;
val it : Set<int> list =
  [set [0; 2]; set [2]; set [0; 1; 2]; set [1; 2]; set [0]; set []; set [0; 1];
   set [1]]
```